# cable connector types

Tags: connector

How can I recognise cable connector? For example I have here 2 connectors, but basically is there any web catalog with list of the most known connectors?

[image]

Comment: Try parametric search someplace like digikey.  Also *measure* key dimensions like contact spacing.  Context can matter too, in terms of knowing what it traditional for the type of product they came from.  And then there's the question of why you need to know - for example you might be able to re-use the wiring harness and connect the far end to something.

Comment: ^^^^   Truth.     Add that there are literally dozens or maybe hundreds of companies making connectors, and many are not in the Digikey catalog.  There are thousands of different, yet similar, connectors out there.    When I have this situation, if possible I won't try to find the exact same connector - I'll replace both pieces with something I know.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is NO sadly.

The variety of connectors used today is bewilderingly huge. Certain makes e.g. Molex, JST have become effectively 'industry standards'. Certain connectors are made to published standards and widely sourced.

In my own case it's simply been a case of learning as you go, aided hugely by the data online now. The catalogues from major distributors are also a help.